# Validating dynamic array in vuelidate

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I am very new to vue and I am trying to validate an array using vuelidate which is used to render a dynamic table. The problem is with the `validation()` method as I can comprehend.

According to vuelidate docs, https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-collections-validation, the `$each` method supports array. When I use it, the validation never fails. However, when I omit `$each`, and, try to validate first index of the array, it returns as corrected - validation fails.

To be more precise, I am trying to validate each added row(s), and if there's a problem with the validation, it'd add a class to the affected row.

Component `App.vue`,
This is the HTML code:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <br>
      <div class="text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" @click="addRow()">Shto</button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <p
        v-for="error of v$.$errors"
        :key="error.$uid"
      >
    <strong>{{ error.$validator }}</strong>
    <small> on property</small>
    <strong>{{ error.$property }}</strong>
    <small> says:</small>
    <strong>{{ error.$message }}</strong>
    </p>
    <form name="articles" @submit.prevent="submitForm">
      <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
          <tr>
            <th>Nr.</th>
            <th class="col-3">Numri</th>
            <th class="col-4">Përshkrimi</th>
            <th class="col-1">Sasia</th>
            <th class="col-1">Çmimi</th>
            <th class="col-2">Shuma</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(item, idx) in items_table" :key="item">
              <td>
                {{idx+1}}
              </td>
              <td>
                <input v-model="item.part_no" name="part_no[]" class="form-control" type="text" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <textarea v-model="item.part_name" name="part_name[]" class="form-control" type="text"></textarea>
                </td>
              <td>
                <input v-model="item.part_qty" name="part_qty[]" class="form-control " type="number" step="0.01">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input v-model="item.part_price" name="part_price[]" class="form-control" type="number" step="0.01">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input :value="item.part_total" name="part_total[]" class="form-control text-center border-0" style="background-color: transparent; font-size: 18 px;" type="text" disabled>
              </td>
              <td>
                <button type="button" @click="deleteRow(idx)" class="btn btn-danger btn-md btn-block">X</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" name="" id="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Valido</button>
      </div>
      </form>
      <div class="text-center">
        <textarea name="" id="verbose_log" cols="70" rows="15" refs="logg"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is the content from `script` tag:

```
<script>
import useVuelidate from '@vuelidate/core'
import { required } from '@vuelidate/validators'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  setup: () => ({ v$: useVuelidate() }),
  validation()  {
    return {
      items_table: {
          $each: {
          part_no: {
            required,
          }
        }
      },
    }
  },
  data() {
    return  {
      items_table: [
            { 
              part_no: '', part_name: '', part_qty: '', part_price: '',  part_total: '' 
            }
      ],
      items_subtotal: 0.00,
      items_total: 0.00,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    deleteRow(index) {
      if(this.items_table.length == 1) {
        this.items_table.splice(index, 1);
        this.items_subtotal = 0.00;
        this.items_total = 0.00;
        this.addRow();
      } else if(this.items_table.length > 0) {
        this.items_table.splice(index, 1);
      }
    },
    addRow() {
      this.items_table.push({part_no: '', part_name: '', part_qty: '', part_price: '',  part_total: ''});
    },
    submitForm() {
    this.v$.$touch();

    //if (this.v$.$error) return;

    console.log(this.v$);

    document.getElementById('verbose_log').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(this.$data, null, 4);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    //
  }
}
</script>
```

For the sake of clarity, I have excluded two methods which calculate line total and the total itself.

Comment: I was able to partially fix this, by using `helpers` with `$each`, like this `$each: helpers.forEach({ ... })`. Now, I'm figuring out how to print each error on affected cell.